# Destructuring error, response from fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch

I want to implement a Go style error-handling-first data fetch in a React component by destructuring the [responseError, response] objects returned from the fetch(). I'm running into this error: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
Which is being triggered by the destructuring syntax.

The fetch works fine when I set it up without destructuring i.e

const res = await fetch(APIurl) .

What I want to do:

```
    let requestBody = {
      query: `
        query {
          users {
            email
          }
        }
      `
    }

    const [resError, res] = await fetch(APIurl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + context.token
      }
    })

    if (resError || !res) {
      console.log('Request failed', resError)
      return
    }

    const [parseError, json] = await res.json()

    if (parseError || !json) {
      console.log('Request failed', parseError)
      return
    }

    const userData = json.data.users

    setUsers(userData)
  }
```

What works currently:

```
    let requestBody = {
      query: `
        query {
          users {
            email
          }
        }
      `
    }

    const res = await fetch(APIurl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + context.token
      }
    })

    if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
      throw new Error('Fetch failed')
    }

    const json = await res.json()

    const userData = json.data.users

    setUsers(userData)
  }
```

I expect the output to be the same, but the destructuring is triggering the error mentioned above. I am trying to replicate the pattern mentioned in this article: https://www.dalejefferson.com/articles/2016-01-25-error-first-pattern-for-es7-async-await/

Comment: try: `const { parseError, json } = await res.json()`

Comment: using that syntax both objects were returned undefined

Comment: `fetch()` returns a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) Object, not a list of values. That's what the Error message says, the returned object is not iterable. The article you reference is from January 2016. I don't know wether that code worked back then, nowadays it contradicts the specification for `fetch()`. Maybe this was from before the spec was finalized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own middleware that handles your Responses.

```
const validate = (req) => {
  // do some magic
  return [err, res];
};
const request = fetch('/api/url');
const [err, res] = validate(request);
```